Source a shell script when loading a modulefile in lua
I am writing some .lua files for loading modules in a HPC system.
Basically the application I want to make a module is Spack, and it has an autocompletion shell script for sourcing it in linux with:
source /apps/spack/share/spack/setup-env.sh

I want to run this command in my .lua file when loading the spack module into the system, I can't get it to work by doing the following:
os.execute('source /apps/spack/share/spack/setup-env.sh')

Note that the module loads fine and I can use spack without any problems, I just want the autocompletion feature to work when loading the module.
Any help is welcome, thank you!

Maybe try to use the io.popen() function

Both os.execute and io.popen create subprocesses having their own environments, so they do not affect host application environment.  So, the task is impossible to achieve using standard Lua functions.

I have managed to do it with this function.
execute{cmd="source /apps/spack/share/spack/setup-env.sh", modeA={"load"}}

Basically it does the source as expected after the module load and it works perfectly.
Just for the record:
I was using this command before but only the autocomplete command worked in spack and when I did a spack load I got the error that I needed to do the source to get the environment variables right.
source_sh("bash", "/apps/spack/share/spack/spack/setup-env.sh")

And the error:
==> Error: spack load requires Spack's shell support. 
To set up shell support, run the command below for your shell. 
For bash/zsh/sh: . /apps/spack/share/spack/

Thanks for all the help provided from everyone :)

Lmod supports sourcing of shell scripts via the   source_sh function:
https://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/260_sh_to_modulefile.html#using-source-sh

Now i find this problem when using the following on the .lua script
source_sh("bash", "/apps/spack/share/spack/setup-env.sh")
==> Error: spack load requires Spack's shell support.
To set up shell support, run the command below for your shell.
For bash/zsh/sh:
. /apps/spack/share/spack/setup-env.sh
